# Opensuse 11.3 with Dell inspiron 1564 wireless

Tags: opensuse, wifi, broadcom

When I was using ubuntu i used to add the cd to software sources and install a package called bcmwl* and the wireless would work immediately. Now on Opensuse the wireless is not working and as a regular user I am not sure what to do exactly ..
I typed dmesg at terminal and i got a long file with "Broadcom 4312 WLAN found" but i am unable to find my network or connect. Please help

Comment: how did you set up the machine? what have you tried to configure the wireless? can you post the result of `iwlist scanning`?

Answer (score 1):

There is an extensive howto on getting the driver and making it work at http://www.susegeek.com/networking/fix-bcm4311431243214322-wireless-in-opensuse-111-and-earlier/